# Add a closing tag

Tags: notepad++

I need to add a closing tag, how can I do this in NotePadd++ using find replace?

```
<cost>975
<release>2013-06-12
```

I need this:

```
<cost>975</cost>
<release>2013-06-12</release>
```

I tried this:

```
<cost>.*
<release>$1$2</release>
```

But it removes the text between the tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<(cost|release)\b.+$` If you want to match all tags, use `<(\w+).+$`
- Replace with: `$0</$1>`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<               # open tag
(cost|release)  # group 1, matches "cost" OR "release"
\b              # word boundary, avoid to match "costs" or "released"
.+              # 1 or more any character but newline
$               # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$0          # the whole match
</$1>       # closing tag with same name
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: +1 I didn't know it was possible to use `$0`.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio: Thanks! It's very usefull, it avoids creating a group for the whole match. It works for PCRE and BOOST flavour, and certainly for more than those two.

Comment: I need to thank you because I have learned a lot with your regular expression answers.

Comment: Thanks, but it adds tags everywhere. And I only need to replace for these <cost>
<release>, is there a solution?

Comment: @Olik: See my update.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing it in two steps.

The first will be :

Find : `<cost>(.*)`
Replace : `<cost>\1</cost>`

In your context you might need `$1` instead of `\1`.

The second step is very similar to the first, using `<release>`.